# Xamarin, Android: OnTimedEvent won't stop after it's launched?

Tags: android, xamarin

So this is wired: 
This is my Countdown:

```
    public void CountDown()
    {

        System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer.Interval = 5000;
        timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;

        if (TimerRunning == true)
        {
            timer.Enabled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            timer.Enabled = false;
            TimerRunning = false; 
        }
```

So, I hand over a boolean from my MainActivity, that sets TimmerRunning = true, when I press the startbutton, and TimerRunning = false, when i press the stopbutton.

This is my OntimedEvend:

```
public void OnTimedEvent(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // Check if really timer is okay to launch
    if (MainActivity.CountDownRunning == true)
    {
        TimerRunning = true;
    }
    else
    {
        TimerRunning = false;
    }

    // Check the checkbox status 
    if (MainActivity.CheckBoxTicked == true)
    {
        var MockingObject = new MockTheLocation(this);
        MockingObject.getMockLocation2PROMODE();

        Log.Info("2", "CountDown ausgeführt! Pro Mode ON");
    }
    else
    {
        var MockingObject = new MockTheLocation(this);
        MockingObject.getMockLocation2();

        Log.Info("2", "CountDown ausgeführt! Pro Mode OFF");
    }
```

So, here is what should happen. 
`OnTimedEvend` gets fired. It checks for the `boolean` from my `MainActivity`, whether the internal bool from this class TimerRunning should be true or false. Now, after 5 seconds my countdown launches again, and gets a `boolean` that is set to false. Now it should set Timer.Enabled to "false". But the event keeps on firing every 5 seconds and I really dont get why?

Any help would be appreciated!!

THANKS :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you only call `CountDown()` for one time, then you either enable the timer or disable it, but based on your description, you have enabled it, then it's possible that you never call `CountDown()` again to disable your timer, otherwise your will subscribe your `Elapsed` event for several times.

Guess what you need is just fire `OnTimedEvent` one time, then you can unsubscribe it for example like this:

```
private System.Timers.Timer timer;

public void CountDown()
{
    timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
    timer.Interval = 5000;
    timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;

    if (TimerRunning == true)
    {
        timer.Enabled = true;
    }
    else
    {
        timer.Enabled = false;
        TimerRunning = false;
    }
}

public void OnTimedEvent(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    // Check if really timer is okay to launch
    if (CountDownRunning == true)
    {
        TimerRunning = true;
    }
    else
    {
        TimerRunning = false;
        timer.Elapsed -= OnTimedEvent;
    }
}
```